# Total voltage towards load?

Tags: voltage

What would be the resulting voltage in a DC circuit like this:

[image]

Where there are three voltage sources, it seems that two are in parallel(20V,5V)
opposing 15V source So would the total voltage be (20V + 5V - 15V?)

Here is the similar circuit but with a load that is at 2 Ohms:

[image]

V1 + V2 are together opposing V3 correct?

Comment: When in doubt, simulate.

Comment: I can't though...

Comment: My brain aches just trying to read that circuit...

Comment: The question is not too clear. I mean you ask about the voltage drop in the load according the title of your question. D1 is always cut-off with this configuration, then voltage drop in Diode2= 0,7 volt (standard value), you have a voltage drop in the load =19,3-15=4,3 V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you present the circuit in your question is very difficult to follow. Here are the same circuits drawn in a more logical way. It helps to take some time to draw the circuits in a way that's easier for others to interpret.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyEb2K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice that V1 and V2 are not strictly in parallel. The diodes isolate them from each other.

The circuit without a load is a little confusing to solve if you're thinking of ideal components. What happens to ideal voltage sources when you connect them together? Infinities are involved. And it doesn't bring us any closer to understanding what's really happening.

Luckily non-ideal components in the real world makes this a little easier. We know immediately that D1 will not conduct. Whatever the voltage on the cathode of D1 is, it'll be larger that 5V. So we can ignore V2 and D1 in both versions of the circuit.

The anode of D2 is 20V, which is larger than the 15V from V3, so D2 will conduct. Right at the cathode of D2 will be 20V minus the forward drop. That will undoubtedly be more than V3's 15V, so current is gonna flow into V3. In the circuit without a load, one of three things will happen.

1) If V1 and V3 are "stiff" enough, they both hold their respective voltages. The current out of V1 and through D2 will increase until the natural resistance of the physical wire connecting D2 to V3 provides the necessary voltage drop according to Ohm's Law. So the voltage on that wire will actually be a linear function along its length. Physically closer to V1, the voltage will be closer to 20V. Physically closer to V3 will be closer to 15V.

2) If V1 is "stiffer" than V3, the current flow into V3 will elevate its voltage to be closer to V1. In that case, the voltage along the wire will be closer to 20V. In a real world battery, this might make V3 explode.

3) If V3 is "stiffer" than V1, the current draw out of V1 will cause V1's voltage to drop. In that case, the voltage along the wire will be closer to 15V.

The circuit with the 2 Ohm resistor is a little easier. Assuming the voltage sources are adequate, the left side of the resistor will be about 20V minus the diode drop. The right side of the resistor will be 15V.

EDIT:
Based on discussion in the comments, it looks like you're trying to come up with a way to make V1 and V3 cancel each other out so V2 dominates. Since you haven't explained exactly why you're doing this, I'll take an academic approach without regard to practical implications.

Voltage sources will cancel each other out if they're *in series* and in *opposite polarity* to each other. **And they do not share a common reference voltage of any kind**. Therefore, to make V1 cancel V3 and allow V2 to dominate, you would simply do the following. Notice the orientation of V3 relative to V1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNttjb.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, what if V1 and V3 we're both equal? They cancel out leaving V2? I'm trying figure out a way to have V1 + V2 - V3 = Vtot, without having current from V2 flow in V1. I assumed if V1 and V3 are equal they would cancel out, leaving V2 remanent.

Comment: Maybe by removing D1, V1 + V2 - V3 will be true?

Comment: If you're trying to add voltage sources together, you're not approaching it in the right way. As long as their ground references are tied together, you can't add or subtract voltages. What exactly are you trying to do? What's your end game? Are V1, V2, and V3 batteries or plug-in-the-wall power sources?

Comment: It's an experiment related thing, where there is V3 opposing V1 and V2, I'm trying to "add" V2 and V1 together without having V2's current flowing in V1 if that make sense.

Comment: They could be any source you would like, one that is of low voltage and is DC.

Comment: With simple voltage sources like batteries, you can simply stack them on top of each other in different orientations. For example, 2 alkaline AAs in series will give you +3.0V. Put a third AA upside-down on the top and it'll subtract 1.5V. You can do that with any fully isolated power supplies. If you're doing this with plug-in-the-wall supplies, however, you may start a fire unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Dan, in the schematic you gave if D2 was not included and V1 = V3, what would happen to V2? - I remembered from the batteries configuration that the voltage sources I have are a bit complicated.  But I will work on the current diagram that I have set up, and study how to make V2 included with V1 to oppose V3. That is my end-game. Having V1 cancel out with V3 leaving V2's input.

Comment: I need a circuit to show you, so I'll edit the answer in a minute here.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure out such a confusion...

Comment: Dan, what if the same is applied in the circuits I presented... however, D1 is removed? So that V1,V3 cancel and what is remaining is V2? Your circuit is the one I had in mind initially, but the circuit I'm working on has solve some problems that you're would present in my study/experiment.

Comment: If you remove D1 from your original circuit, you would short V1 and V3 into V2. That's not good. Like I said in one of my comments above, if you have the ground references tied together (like you do in your original circuit), you cannot add or subtract the voltages.

Comment: Dan, you said that they would only cancel if they are in series. What if they we're in parallel?

Comment: Putting voltage sources in parallel does not add or subtract their values. If two sources of the same voltage are combined in parallel, the final voltage doesn't change, but the current capacity increases. If the voltages are different, then the higher one will attempt to force current into the lower one, which will probably result in spectacular failure.

Comment: If they we're equal voltage, and have equal induced current going in opposition they currents cancel out? Or